# Distribution with CDDL dependency in case of intellij

Tags: licensing

I have an amateur question with respect to [CDDL 1.0 License](https://opensource.org/licenses/CDDL-1.0).

This [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Third-Party+Software+Used+by+IntelliJ+IDEA+15) provides a list of all the open source software used by intellij idea. The one in relevance now for this ticket is: [WADL-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.ws.wadl/wadl-core) that it uses which is licensed to CDDL 1.0.

Now CDDL 1.0 demands that the source of the library also be distributed along with the software. I downloaded intellij idea 2018.1, and accessed the lib folder. I do see `wadl-core.jar` file in its lib folder.

But the jar does not contain the source files within it, nor do I find the source of `wadl-core` anywhere else. So how does intellij comply to the license?

> j@p:~/awesome/ideaIC-2018.1.5$ find . -name '*wadl*'
>
> ./idea-IC-181.5281.24/lib/wadl-core.jar

I am asking this question, because I am planning to have a software that will have dependency on other libraries which has CDDL 1.0 license. And I need to be safe with distribution of my software.

Comment: -1. Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

> Now CDDL 1.0 demands that the source of the library also be distributed along with the software.

I can't see anything in the license that says that. Specifically, what it says is that the software must be "made available in Source Code form". This doesn't mean it needs to be distributed along with the binary, just that it is available to download somewhere. In the case of WADL, it looks like the source-code is available to download at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/javaee/wadl)...